# Parsing JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

This is the json file I want to parse

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "name": {
                "title": "mr",
                "first": "brad",
                "last": "gibson"
            },
            "location": {
                "street": "9278 new road",
                "city": "kilcoole",
                "state": "waterford",
                "postcode": "93027",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": "20.9267",
                    "longitude": "-7.9310"
                }
            },
            "picture": {
                "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/75.jpg",
                "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/75.jpg",
                "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can easily access the first element i.e(gender) using

```
 response = requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
 data = response.json()

 ans = data['results'][0]['gender']
 print(ans)
```

but I am not getting how to access elements of "name" i.e title,first,last

I tried

```
ans = data['results'][1]['name'][0]['title']
```

Error: index out of bound

Comment: Use quotes to access the name field : `data['results'][1]['name'][0]`. Here you are trying to use the name variable instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name needs to be in quotations.

Change from this format.

```
ans = data['results'][1][name][0]
```

To this

```
ans = data['results'][0]['name']['first']
```

Comment: But the list has only one element

Comment: @shaswatkumar did this work? ans = data['results'][0]['name']['first']

Comment: Okay, but there are more changes I have made than just the typo, please do try it.

Comment: There is no `['name'][0]`. As such, this answer is correct (as is @ekneiling's)

Comment: But how are we accessing 'name' i.e 1st index using [0] i.e same as 'gender'

Comment: Yes, because they're all present in the same list and since there is only one element, it's a '0'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's only one result, so use the same index as you did for gender. Also, name is a `dict` not a `list`

```
ans = data['results'][0]['name']['title']
```